# display picker when clicking in imagebutton xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagebutton, picker

i want to display a picker (or list) when i click in my imageButton but it didn't work, but when i create only a picker , it worked.

Xaml

```
     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stacklayout">
                <Entry Placeholder="préciser l'entité correspondante" 
                       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing" x:Name="entit"/>

                <ImageButton Source="list.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" x:Name="listEntité" Clicked="listEntité_Clicked"/>
```

Xaml.cs

```
 private void listEntité_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

               Picker p = new Picker();
              HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
              httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.3:3000/api/adepApi/GetCurrencyLists");
              httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
              HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://192.168.1.3:3000/api/adepApi/GetCurrencyLists");
              var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              ResponseDataD EL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseDataD>(content);
              p.ItemsSource= EL.Data.DeviseList;
              stacklayout.Children.Add(p.ItemsSource);


          }
```

class DeviseModel

```
  public class DeviseModel
{
    public class DeviseL
    {
     //   public string devis;
        [JsonProperty("Label")]

        public string Devis { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Value")]

        public int id { get; set; }


    }
    public class ResponseDataD
    {
        public RootModelDevise Data;
    }
    public class RootModelDevise : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        List<DeviseL> deviseList;

        [JsonProperty("list")]
        public List<DeviseL> DeviseList
        {
            get { return deviseList; }
            set
            {
                if (deviseList != value)
                {
                    deviseList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        DeviseL itemDevise;
        public DeviseL ItemDevise
        {
            get { return itemDevise; }
            set
            {
                if (itemDevise != value)
                {
                    itemDevise = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {

            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;
            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));               
   }
}}
```

i have an error in the line 
    stacklayout.Children.Add(p.ItemsSource);
under p.itemsSource :unable to convert from 'System.Collections.Ilist' to 'Xamarin.Forms.View'

Comment: Firstly, you don't add tapGestureRecognizer for ImageButton, so  tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped never fire, picker can not display. Then I try to add TapGestureRecognizer for ImageButton correctly, tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped also can not be fired, I guess that it may be conflict with the click event, you can see this :https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4341, so I suggest you can add picker by imagebutton click event.

Comment: Where is it supposed to show Picker visually, your Xaml /C#code doesnt show it. Is it below ImageButton ? if yes what is the parent view of ImageButton?

Comment: i have tried to add picker by imageButton click event , but nothing appears.. @CherryBu-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have tried to add picker by imageButton click event , but nothing appears.

Firstly, please confirm that the EL.Data.DeviseList have list value, you have list binding to Picker, then adding picker to current contentPage.

```
public partial class Page16 : ContentPage
{
    private List<string> list;
    public Page16()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = new List<string>();

        list.Add("test 1");
        list.Add("test 2");
        list.Add("test 3");
        list.Add("test 4");

    }

    private void imagebutton1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker p = new Picker();
        p.ItemsSource = list;
        stacklayout.Children.Add(p);
    }
}

 <StackLayout x:Name="stacklayout">
        <ImageButton
            x:Name="imagebutton1"
            Clicked="imagebutton1_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="30"
            Source="plu3.png"
            WidthRequest="30" />

    </StackLayout>
```

**Update:**

```
 private void imagebutton1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker p = new Picker();
        p.SelectedIndexChanged += P_SelectedIndexChanged;
        p.ItemsSource = devs;     
        p.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Devis");

        stacklayout.Children.Add(p);
    }

    private void P_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Picker p = sender as Picker;
        DeviseL selectitem = p.SelectedItem as DeviseL;
        entit.Text =selectitem.Devis;
    }
```

Comment: can you see the update of the publication please ? i found an error when i tried to do the same as you do, but with consuming a service (that has the list)

Comment: @wafa You can see I name one stacklayout as stacklayout, then I want to add Picker to add this stacklayout, but you want to add Picker.itemsource to stacklayout, Picker.itemsource is the list collection, it is mistake.

Comment: so what should i do ? Can you help mee please!

Comment: @wafa Please try to modify your code `stacklayout.Children.Add(p.ItemsSource);` using `stacklayout.Children.Add(p)`

Comment: it displayed to me a list but it is not of the wanted list, what is displayed is a list containing "NotesDesFrais.views.DeviseModel + DeviseL" (this is the path of the class DeviseModel) repeated 7 time.  :(

Comment: @wafa So please check what is the EL.Data.DeviseList? It is the List<DeviseL> or other collection?

Comment: it is the List<DeviseL>

Comment: @wafawa Adding following code `p.ItemsSource= EL.Data.DeviseList; p.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Devis");stacklayout.Children.Add(p)`

Comment: thank you very much ! i got the result that i wanted :) thank you !!

Comment: just this question please,(i am sorry) if i want to affect this item selected from picker to an entry , what should i do ? when i use entit.Text=p.SelectedItem.ToString(); it does not work  (entit is the x:Name of Entry )